# Why video is not uploading with this file uploading system?(uploading images is okay.)

Tags: php, mysql

I think I created a file uploading in database and show from database system. In this file uploading system I can upload images. But videos are not being uploaded. What should I change to upload videos as well as images?

```php
    <?php
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'prac');
    $topic=$_POST['topic'];
    $text=$_POST['caption'];
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

    $sql= "INSERT INTO post(topic, caption, image) VALUES ('$topic', '$text', '$image')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target)){
        $msg="Image Uploaded";
    }
    else{
        $msg="Problem uploading image";
    }

}
?>
```

```html
<?php echo $msg ?>
<div id="content">
<form method="POST" action="prac.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="100000">
<select name="topic" required>
    <option></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="caption" placeholder="caption">
<input type="file" name="image">
<button type="submit" name="submit">POST </button>
</form>
```

```php
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'prac');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
$result= mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>"."<img src='images/".$row['image']."' height='300px' max-width='100%'>"."</tr>";
    echo "<tr>"."<p>".$row['caption']."</p>"."</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what error message are you getting? I wouldn't store the video contents in the DB. instead store it on file and store the dir in the DB. Also use parameterized queries you're opening yourself up for sql injections.

Comment: any error or warnings are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Comment: @altoids how to do that, any youtube tutorial/ link suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for videos and images uploads with the validation .

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wmav","3gp", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "video/mp4")|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "audio/wma")|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png")|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

{
if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
"uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
}
}
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}
}
```